# Can I load static media inside of a .less file?

Tags: css, django, less

I have a .less file used for styling my webpage. I want to display an icon which has a background pointing to a URL:

```
background:transparent url("{% static 'images/icons/myicon.svg ' %}") center top no-repeat;
```

What I want to do is add this to the rules for `.my_icon`:

```
.my_icon {

 width: 40px;
 height:40px;
 display:block;
 background:transparent url("{% static 'images/icons/myicon.svg ' %}") center top no-repeat;
}
```

Can I do this by putting `{% load static %}` at the stop of my style.less file? It does not seem to be working for me.

Comment: this is a good question, this isnt the answer but a hacky fix is to prefix your url with the static path instead of relying on the tags to dynamically generate it. ie add `/static/` instead.

Comment: I found that my issue was due to an unrelated problem. However I tested just changing the paths manually to point to /static/ and it works. Less throws an "unrecognized input" error when to try to do {% load static %}.

Comment: Exactly i was tackling this today myself.